# Nothing happens after the call to android AccountManager

Tags: android

I'm playing with account manager, and I managed to make it work creating an account for me.
But after some changes in the code it stopped working.

I'm calling [AccountManager.addAccount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addAccount%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) and expecting my service to be binded. But no intent seems to be sent to me despite appropriate filters are configured:

```
  <service 
    android:name=".service.MyService"
    android:exported="true"
    >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
      android:resource="@xml/authenticator" 
      />
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
      android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" 
      />
</service>
```

I also see nothing in logs.
Has anyone suggestions about the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually rebooting emulator helped me...